# Encoding Chinese characters in Python and TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, string, csv, encoding, chinese-locale

Hi guys I've written a web scraper in Python trying to scrape some words sample sentences and so on from a dictionary-ish website for my GRE word list and put them in a csv file. The scraping content includes Chinese characters.

The only problem to my script is when I am trying to write those out to a CSV file, I could either get an error of

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 13-15: ordinal not in range(128)

or

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Here is my complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-

from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# make a word list (grabbed from the wordlist pdf, converted to Excel and extracted)

wordList = '''Day One
abandon
abate
abbreviate
Day Two
abate
abbreviate
Day Three
abandon
abate
Day Four
abandon
abate
abandon
abate
Day Five
abandon
abate
Day Six
abandon
abate
Day Seven
abandon
abate'''

wordList = [y for y in (x.strip() for x in wordList.splitlines()) if y]

dayIndex = 0
dayArray = ['Day One', 'Day Two', 'Day Three', 'Day Four', 'Day Five', 'Day Six', 'Day Seven']

for item in wordList:
        if item == dayArray[dayIndex]:
                if dayIndex == 0:
                        fileName = "Word " + dayArray[dayIndex] + ".csv"
                        f = open(fileName, 'w')
                        headers = "word, separater, detail, lineSep\n"
                        f.write(headers)
                        dayIndex += 1
                elif dayIndex == 6:
                        f.close()
                else:
                        f.close()
                        fileName = "Word " + dayArray[dayIndex] + ".csv"
                        f = open(fileName, 'w')
                        headers = "word, separater, detail, lineSep\n"
                        f.write(headers)
                        dayIndex += 1
        else:
                # construct url for each word
                myUrl = 'http://gre.kmf.com/vocab/detail/' + item

                # opening up the connection, grabbing the page
                uClient = uReq(myUrl)
                page_html = uClient.read()
                uClient.close()

                # html parsing
                pageSoup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

                # grab word container
                container = pageSoup.findAll("div", {"class", "word-d-maintile"})
                contain = container[0]# actually only 1 item in the container array

                # grab the word(should be the same as item)
                word = contain.span.text

                # grab word detail
                wordDetail_container = contain.findAll("div", {"class": "word-g-translate"})
                wordDetail = wordDetail_container[0].text.strip()# again should be only 1 item in the array.strip() the extra spaces and useless indentation

                # manipulate the string wordDetail(string is immutable but you know what I mean)
                detailArray = []
                for letter in wordDetail:
                        if letter != '【' and letter != '例' and letter != '近' and letter != '反':
                            detailArray.append(letter)
                        elif letter == '【':
                            detailArray.append("\n\n\n" + letter)
                        else:
                            detailArray.append("\n\n" + '[' + letter + ']' + ' ')
                        newWordDetail = ''.join(detailArray)
                #print("CUT\n") debug
                #print(word + '\n') debug
                #print(newWordDetail) debug
                f.write(word +',' + '&' + ',' + newWordDetail.replace(',', 'douhao') + ',' + '$')
```

The problem is at the last line. When the first error occurs I added a ".encode('gb2312')" after the newWordDetail trying to encode those Chinese characters, but after I did that I got the second error. I've checked online but hardly found a solution suiting my situation.

Thanks guys for saving my life!

Comment: On the 2nd line should specify the encoding name, i.e. `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Thanks downshift I copied these two lines from a SO question but didn't notice the content... I've added it but still the code doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

你的代码，写成了面条式代码，造成有的情况下，文件关闭了，不能写。

f.write(word + ',' + '&' + ',' +newWordDetail.replace(',', 'douhao') + ',' + '$')

sometime  you write to a close file， so this is wrong. below code is correct, run this code ,I can get correct content.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8
'''黄哥Python'''


from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# make a word list (grabbed from the wordlist pdf, converted to Excel and
# extracted)

wordList = '''Day One
abandon
abate
abbreviate
Day Two
abate
abbreviate
Day Three
abandon
abate
Day Four
abandon
abate
abandon
abate
Day Five
abandon
abate
Day Six
abandon
abate
Day Seven
abandon
abate'''

wordList = [y for y in (x.strip() for x in wordList.splitlines()) if y]

dayIndex = 0
dayArray = ['Day One', 'Day Two', 'Day Three',
            'Day Four', 'Day Five', 'Day Six', 'Day Seven']

for item in wordList:
    if item == dayArray[dayIndex]:
        if dayIndex == 0:
            fileName = "Word " + dayArray[dayIndex] + ".csv"
            f = open(fileName, 'w')
            headers = "word, separater, detail, lineSep\n"
            f.write(headers)
            dayIndex += 1
        elif dayIndex == 6:
            f.close()
        else:
            f.close()
            fileName = "Word " + dayArray[dayIndex] + ".csv"
            f = open(fileName, 'w')
            headers = "word, separater, detail, lineSep\n"
            f.write(headers)
            dayIndex += 1
    else:
        # construct url for each word
        myUrl = 'http://gre.kmf.com/vocab/detail/' + item

        # opening up the connection, grabbing the page
        uClient = uReq(myUrl)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()

        # html parsing
        pageSoup = soup(page_html, "html.parser", )

        # grab word container
        container = pageSoup.findAll("div", {"class", "word-d-maintile"})
        contain = container[0]  # actually only 1 item in the container array

        # grab the word(should be the same as item)
        word = contain.span.text

        # grab word detail
        wordDetail_container = contain.findAll(
            "div", {"class": "word-g-translate"})
        # again should be only 1 item in the array.strip() the extra spaces and
        # useless indentation
        wordDetail = wordDetail_container[0].text.strip()

        # manipulate the string wordDetail(string is immutable but you know
        # what I mean)
        detailArray = []
        for letter in wordDetail:
            if letter != '【' and letter != '例' and letter != '近' and letter != '反':
                detailArray.append(letter)
            elif letter == '【':
                detailArray.append("\n\n\n" + letter)
            else:
                detailArray.append("\n\n" + '[' + letter + ']' + ' ')
            newWordDetail = ''.join(detailArray)
        # print("CUT\n") debug
        # print(word + '\n') debug
        # print(newWordDetail) debug
        # print(f)
        try:
            f.write(word + ',' + '&' + ',' +newWordDetail.replace(',', 'douhao') + ',' + '$')
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

输出结果，其中一个文件的内容如下。
word, separater, detail, lineSep
abandon,&,

【考法1】n. 放纵： carefreedouhao freedom from constraint

[例] add spices to the stew with complete abandon 肆无忌惮地向炖菜里面加调料

[近] unconstraintdouhao uninhibitednessdouhao unrestraint

【考法2】v. 放纵： to give （oneself） over unrestrainedly

[例] abandon oneself to emotion 感情用事 ‖ abandon herself to a life of complete idleness 她放纵自己过着闲散的生活

[近] indulgedouhao surrender

【考法3】v. 放弃： to withdraw from often in the face of danger or encroachment

[例] abandon the ship/homes 弃船； 离家

[反] salvage 救援

【考法4】v. 停止做某事： to put an end to （something planned or previously agreed to）

[例] The bad weather forced NASA to abandon the launch. 坏天气迫使NASA停止了发射。

[近] abortdouhao dropdouhao repealdouhao rescinddouhao revokedouhao call offdouhao give up

[反] keepdouhao continuedouhao maintaindouhao carry on  继续,$abate,&,

【考法1】v. 减轻（程度或者强度）： to reduce in degree or intensity

[例] abate his rage/pain 平息他的愤怒 / 减轻他的痛苦

[近] moderatedouhao recededouhao subsidedouhao remitdouhao wanedouhao die （away or down or out）douhao let updouhao phase downdouhao taper off

[反] intensify加强， 加剧

【考法2】v. 减少（数量）， 降低（价值）： to reduce in amount or value

[例] abate a tax 降低税收

[近] de-escalatedouhao depletedouhao downscaledouhao dwindledouhao ratchet （down）

[反] augmentdouhao promote 增加

【考法3】v. 停止， 撤销： to put an end to

[例] abate a nuisance 停止伤害

[近] abrogatedouhao annuldouhao invalidatedouhao nullifydouhao rescinddouhao vacate,$

Comment: Hi 黄哥 yea sure at first I thought it could run into copyright issue so I replaced the true url, but I just figured out I can changed that later so I have now changed to the correct url. Thanks for your help!

Comment: pageSoup = soup(page_html, "html.parser", from_encoding='gbk')

Comment: Thanks 黄哥 let me try

Comment: Hi 黄哥 I have added from_encoding='gbk' but it still won't work... Same problem...

Comment: # -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-  change  to # coding:utf-8  and pageSoup = soup(page_html, "html.parser", from_encoding='gbk') or pageSoup = soup(page_html, "html.parser", from_encoding='utf-8')

Comment: Hi 黄哥 the correct url is already in the code. The methods you gave do not work in my side. Will you be able to debug my code by the correct url?

Comment: Hi Thanks 黄哥 sorry for the late reply. I just copied your code to my machine to run but it seems it stuck on the file writing command and the file created has nothing in it. Also I've tried running it on AWS Ubuntu machine with no luck. However I believe that it could run in your machine. Do you have any idea that what could be possibly wrong? Did you run it at a Chinese-locale based machine or?

Comment: maybe  forbid you IP,  not about  code, do you know?

Comment: you can print(page_html)  test page_html  has value or not ?

Comment: Hi 黄哥 sorry for the late reply. IP shouldn't be a problem as when I just ran my code and printed the fetched content in console, the content is fetched and formatted correctly. And I guess then print(page_html) will print the content as well.